# Seeking clarification on transaction nonce

Tags: go-ethereum

seeking clarification regarding the concept of “nonce.” I’ve noticed that when I send a transaction with a randomly chosen nonce, it generates a hash, but I never seem to receive a transaction receipt. However, when I use the web3.eth.get_transaction_count(account.address) function to retrieve the account’s nonce and use that in my transaction, it  generates a hash and provides a receipt ?

Comment: Transaction's nonces should be consecutive numbers starting from 0. They aren't random values.